# setting datacontext for a view in a tab item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

in my window resources i have a datatemplate for my viewmodel and a static mainviewmodel

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SharedViewModels:DatabaseViewModel}">
            <SharedViews:DatabaseView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <LocalViewModels:SharedSettingsViewModel x:Key="SharedSettingsViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

`DatabaseViewModel` is an instance in my static `SharedSettingsViewModel`
and i have this tab control

```
<TabControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SharedSettingsViewModel}}" ItemsSource="{Binding SharedSettingsViewModelsTabList}">
                        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </TabControl>
```

and i add items to my TabControl itemssorce like this

```
SharedSettingsViewModelTabList.Add(new Shared.Models.TabItem() { Header = "Sql Databases", Content = DatabaseViewModel });
```

How do set the datacontext of my `DatabaseView` to the `DatabaseViewModel` instance that is inside my `SharedSettingsViewModel`?

in my view DatabaseView XAML  which is a user control i tried

```
DataContext="{Binding DatabaseViewModel}"
```

but this doesnt seem to work

here is my TabItem Model

```
public class TabItem : MVVM.ObservableObject
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public MVVM.ObservableObject Content { get; set; }
    }
```

my DatabaseViewModel which will be defined as a Property in SharedSettingsViewModel

```
 private ObservableCollection<Models.Database> databases;

 public ObservableCollection<Models.Database> Databases
        {
            get
            {
                if (databases == null)
                {
                    databases = new ObservableCollection<Models.Database>();
                    databases.Add(new Models.Database() { Displayname = "new" });
                }
                return databases;
            }
            set
            {
                SetField(ref databases, value, "Databases");
            }
        }
```

and here is my SharedSettingsViewModel which contains the tab items collection

```
public class SharedSettingsViewModel : MVVM.ObservableObject 
    {
    private ObservableCollection<Shared.Models.TabItem> SharedSettingsViewModelTabList;
    public ObservableCollection<Shared.Models.TabItem> SharedSettingsViewModelTabList
            {
                get
                {
                    if (sharedSettingsViewModelTabList == null)
                    {
                        sharedSettingsViewModelTabList = new ObservableCollection<Shared.Models.TabItem>();
                    }
                    return sharedSettingsViewModelTabList;
                }

            }

    //my DatabaseViewModel property..as a child view model

            private Shared.ViewModels.DatabaseViewModel databaseViewModel;
            public Shared.ViewModels.DatabaseViewModel DatabaseViewModel
            {
                get
                {
                    if (databaseViewModel == null)
                    {
                        databaseViewModel = new Shared.ViewModels.DatabaseViewModel();
                    }
                    return databaseViewModel;
                }
                set
                {
                    SetField(ref databaseViewModel, value, "DatabaseViewModel");
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update the code as below and your `DatabaseViewModel` will become the `DataContext` of your `DatabaseView` which will be the `DataTemplate` for the `Content` of `ContentPresenter` in `ContentTemplate` of your `TabControl`

```
       <TabControlDataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SharedSettingsViewModel}}" ItemsSource="{Binding SharedSettingsViewModelsTabList}">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
```